# Move span jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Tell me how to use jQuery to move objects. I need to move inside each label `span.over-span` inside `span.wpcf7-form-control-wrap`.
It is necessary that the `over-span` was next to the input. Such a label with nesting I have 3 per page. This requires an identical movement within each one.

The structure is:

```
<label>
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap text-377">
        <input type="text" name="text-377" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-not-valid" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true" placeholder="Name">
    </span>
    <span class="over-span">Name</span><br>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, you have to select all `span.over-span`, then, select all `span.wpcf7-form-control-wrap` and iterate through them using `.each()` method. And inside this loop, we can `append` by one item from `target` array (I'm using `$(this).append(target[i])`, it's the same as `$("span.wpcf7-form-control-wrap")[i].append(target[i])`). There is no visible changes after this operation, but you can inspect elements and be sure, that `<span class="over-span"></span>` is inside `<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap text-377"></span>` and goes after the `input` element:

```js
var target = $("span.over-span");
$("span.wpcf7-form-control-wrap").each(function(i) {
  $(this).append(target[i]);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap text-377">
    <input type="text" name="text-377" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-not-valid" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true" placeholder="Name">
  </span>
  <span class="over-span">Name1</span><br>
</label>

<label>
  <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap text-377">
    <input type="text" name="text-377" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-not-valid" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true" placeholder="Name">
  </span>
  <span class="over-span">Name2</span><br>
</label>

<label>
  <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap text-377">
    <input type="text" name="text-377" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-not-valid" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true" placeholder="Name">
  </span>
  <span class="over-span">Name3</span><br>
</label>
```